# Error on enabling add on: Animation Mixamo Rig

Tags: python, add-on, mixamo

I've just installed the latest version of the add-on *Animation: Mixamo Rig* and the following error appears:

[image]

...the Blender version I'm using is Blender 4.0.

Comment: It looks like the addon needs to be updated for the API changes in Blender 4.0. In the meantime you need to use a previous version.

Comment: The addon available [on Mixamo's website](https://substance3d.adobe.com/plugins/mixamo-in-blender/) seem to have not been updated since v2.80 

Comment: That's one of the addons which wasn't automatically transferred from 3.65 to 4.0 when I installed it so I think @Gorgious is correct.

Comment: Made a fix, And a quick tutorial, to show you how to do it... https://youtu.be/40-j4FtE8Uo

Comment: try to use this modified addon [Mixamo rig 4.0+](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G71J1TgZ9sX-LRx1uU8SdrZA4UUwxtLz/view?pli=1)